# Why the value of clientHeight of <li> element does not change when scrolling?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to hide the `<li></li>` element when it's overflowing (while scrolling, and just before scrolling after adding some products to the shopping cart), however, the clientHeight on the overflowingRef, which refers to the `<li></li>` element does not change when its content is overflowing. Any idea what i m doing wrong?

Please see the code for reference below:

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import products from './mock.json';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <ShoppingCart products={products} />
    </div>
  );
}
function List({products, title, addProduct, removeProduct}) {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'start-end',
      }}
    >
      {title}
      <ul
        style={{
          listStyle: 'none',
          paddingInlineStart: '0px',
          width: '500px',
          height: '260px',
          overflow: 'scroll',
          paddingRight: '10px',
        }}
      >
        {products.length === 0 ? (
          <div>No products</div>
        ) : (
          products.map(({category, price, stocked, name}, index) => (
            <SuspendDisplayIfOverflowing>
              {ref => (
                <li
                  style={{
                    padding: '10px',
                    border: '1px solid blue',
                    display: 'flex',
                    justifyContent: 'space-between',
                    height: '18px',
                    overflow: 'scroll',
                  }}
                  ref={ref}
                  key={price}
                >
                  <div style={{color: `${stocked ? 'green' : 'red'}`}}>
                    {`${name} - ${category} - available: ${stocked} - price: ${price}`}
                  </div>
                  {addProduct && stocked ? (
                    <button
                      onClick={() =>
                        addProduct({category, price, stocked, name})
                      }
                    >
                      Add
                    </button>
                  ) : null}
                  {removeProduct ? (
                    <button onClick={() => removeProduct(index)}>Remove</button>
                  ) : null}
                </li>
              )}
            </SuspendDisplayIfOverflowing>
          ))
        )}
      </ul>
      <Total prices={products.map(({price}) => getCleanPrice(price))} />
    </div>
  );
}

function ShoppingCart({products}) {
  const [productsInCart, manipulateProduct] = useState([]);
  const addProduct = product =>
    manipulateProduct(productsInCart.concat(product));
  const removeProduct = productIndex =>
    manipulateProduct(
      productsInCart.filter((_, index) => index !== productIndex),
    );

  return (
    <>
      <List
        title="Available Products"
        products={products}
        addProduct={addProduct}
      />
      <List
        title="Shopping Cart"
        products={productsInCart}
        removeProduct={removeProduct}
      />
    </>
  );
}

function Total({prices}) {
  const total = prices.reduce((accum, item) => (accum += parseFloat(item)), 0);
  return <div>Total amount to pay: {total.toFixed(2)}</div>;
}

function getCleanPrice(price) {
  return price.slice(1);
}

function SuspendDisplayIfOverflowing(props) {
  const overflowingRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(
      'oveflowing scroll height',
      overflowingRef.current.scrollHeight,
    );
    console.log(
      'oveflowing client height',
      overflowingRef.current.clientHeight,
    );
    console.log(
      'oveflowing client height',
      overflowingRef.current.offsetHeight,
    );
    console.log(overflowingRef.current);
  }, [overflowingRef]);
  return props.children(overflowingRef);
}
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/1orwylonw3 -> to see the output from console.log add 7 products to the shopping cart

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, do you want to hide the left panel, while scrolling? or i haven't understood right?

Comment: I want to hide a product on the right list (the selected products) which is overflowing - does not fit the remaining height of the list.

Comment: I was away, check this https://codesandbox.io/s/zw6k4wjkrl .